# Marker is not appearing on android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-studio-2.3

I am trying to add a marker to the Android Google Maps API using Android Studio. When I run it doesn't show the maker and will not zoom into area.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapWindow extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_window);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapWindow.this);
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no custom marker related code...and what is `breaks` ? mean

Comment: sorry thats what i am to add but when i run in android studio it says that the app stopped (crashed)

Comment: you should post the logcat error appear in android studio..`Android Monitor`...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 just updated to get it to work but the marker doesnt display on map

Comment: @TomHaywood take a look at this [tutorial](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) from google map